# How do i center align my navbar using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have tried so many things but none seem to work
This is my final goal with navbar:

[image: navbar]

and this is what i have right now:

[image: now]

I can't seem to center the links no matter what i do

heres my code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-transparent">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="./index.html"><img src="./images/logo.png" class="img-responsive logo"></a>
        </div>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#work">work</a></li>
                <li><a href="#about">about</a></li>
                <li><a href="#skills">skills</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
                <li><a href="#contact" >get in touch</a>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-transparent">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="./index.html"><img src="./images/logo.png" class="img-responsive logo"></a>
    </div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-firstnav">
            <li><a href="#work">work</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">about</a></li>
            <li><a href="#skills">skills</a></li>
            <li class="pull-right"><a href="#contact">get in touch</a>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
.navbar-nav {
    float:none;
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}

.navbar-firstnav>li {
    display: inline-block;
    float:none;
}
```

[Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/xgeDjE3r1g)

Comment: Thanks! It worked! But now the "get in touch" is in next line, any idea how to get it back up there?

Comment: @Uzer check my edited answer. It was because you had 2 `<ul>`'s.. you could've just used 1. let me know if it works.

Comment: Yes thank you once again! It worked. It wasn't working when i tried adding pull right to it before so i added another ul for it

Answer (score 1):

> You can view a demo [here](http://www.bootply.com/0qisGj3PYQ)

**HTML**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-transparent">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="./index.html"><img src="./images/logo.png" class="img-responsive logo"></a>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-firstnav">
            <li><a href="#work">work</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">about</a></li>
            <li><a href="#skills">skills</a></li>
            <li class="pull-right"><a href="#contact" >get in touch</a>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.navbar {
    border-radius: 0;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(0deg ,#232326 ,#5F695E);
}
.navbar-nav {
    float:none;
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}
.navbar-firstnav>li {
    display: inline-block;
    float:none;
}
.navbar-firstnav>li>a {
    color: #FFF;
}
.navbar-firstnav>li>a:hover {
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: underline;
    background: none
}
```

Comment: @Uzer You can check out the working example using the link provided in the answer

Answer (score 0):

Are you floating your `li` elements? Floating the `ul`? If not have you tried applying the `text-align: center;` to your `ul`?

Comment: I don't have any css added to it, only the normal bootstrap one

Answer (score 0):

You will need to modify some CSS rules for Navbar component. So add a class `center` to `nav.navbar` and the following rules:

```
.navbar.center .navbar-inner {
    text-align: center;
}

.navbar.center .navbar-inner .nav {
    display:inline-block;
    float: none;
}
```